# Plots not working in for loop i am getting only the last element plot

Tags: loops, dataframe, machine-learning, boxplot

df is my dataframe for house recursion

```
for i in df.select_dtypes('int64'):
    sns.boxplot(x=df[i])
```

Output : im getting only the last element

Comment: i cannot attach o/p image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a `subplot` in order to plot multiple plots in one figure. I hope following example will help you out :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
numeric_variables = list(titanic.select_dtypes('int64').columns)
for i, c in enumerate(numeric_variables, 1):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i) 
    g = sns.boxplot(x=c, y="fare",data=titanic)
```

[image]

Comment: why are we using (numeric_values,1): what is the role of 1 here that means c is storing 1 each time?

Comment: subplot; is it derived from matlab?

Comment: `enumerate(numeric_variables, 1)` will make sure your index starts from 1. I created 4 spaces using plt.subplot(2,2,i) and `i` make sure I will select each one in the iteration. yes. subplot is from [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)